# Data Services : Timestamp

Tags: timestamp

On Data Services, I have a job, and I want to stock and display the date and time of the beginning of the processing (start of the execution of the job) and the date and time of end of treatment (end of the execution of the job).
How then I do please?

Thanks

Comment: What Language you are using atleast Mention that??? try google You can easily find that if you are using commonly used languages.

Comment: it's on BODS (data services)

Comment: I have find, thank you